# How to check is upload file is CSV or XLS

Tags: php, csv, xls, file-type

I upload CSV or XLS file and import that file content in to the data base. There is two separate method for read CSV and XLS file read(`readCSV()` and `readXLS()`). when i upload CSV or XLS file that gave to me same file type

```
if(file_type($my_file) =='CSV'){
  readCSV();
}else{
  readXLS();
}
```

How can i write file_type() function for get separate result for CSV and XLS files

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$chunks = basename($your_file_path).explode('.');
if(strtolower($chunks[count($chunks)-1]) == 'csv'){
  //csv
}else{
 //whatever
}
```

Comment: how about file name don't have `.csv` part

Comment: yes of course, sorry for unclear of my question. anyone can upload CSV file name like `abc` if that happen how can i get separate file as CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$extension = end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']));

if($extension == 'csv' || $extension == 'xls')
{
   echo 'ok';
}
else
{
   echo 'error';
}
```

- Thanks

Comment: how about file name with out extenstion