# How to check the uploaded file is csv or xls in python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

[How to check is upload file is CSV or XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417611/how-to-check-is-upload-file-is-csv-or-xls) .
How to check it in python. I'm importing a file to a binary field in openerp which can be retrived as a binary object. I need to read the file and import the data to a table. User can upload csv or xls file. By knowing only I can use the csv package or xlrd package.

Comment: Wouldn't an XLS/XLSX be encoded in bytes? The CSV is just a standard text file.

Comment: In general you only can guess. The only clean solution is to get the "Content-Type" of the HTTP request. Binary data can be anything if you don't specify what it is. That is the reason for the Content-Type field.

Comment: See my solution below. I have tested it for validity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [hex signature for an `.xls`](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) file is the following:

Excel spreadsheet subheader (MS Office)

`09 08 10 00 00 06 05 00 [512 byte offset]`

You can read about the other various signatures on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

I believe that you can do something like this. This is untested, but you can fiddle around with it until it works. Please leave comments for any suggestions or changes. Thanks!

```
xls_sig = b'\x09\x08\x10\x00\x00\x06\x05\x00'
offset = 512
size = 8

with open('spreadsheet.xls', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(offset)       # Seek to the offset.
    bytes = f.read(size) # Capture the specified number of bytes.

    if bytes == xls_sig:
        print 'Uploaded file is an xls.'
    else:
        print 'File is not an xls.'
```

### Update 1

Tested this and I can verify that it works for detecting `.xls` files.

### Update 2

I developed a program to determine if the file is an xls or xlsx:

```
import codecs

xlsx_sig = b'\x50\x4B\x05\06'
xls_sig = b'\x09\x08\x10\x00\x00\x06\x05\x00'

filenames = [
    ('spreadsheet.xls', 0, 512, 8),
    ('spreadsheet.xlsx', 2, -22, 4)]

for filename, whence, offset, size in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(offset, whence) # Seek to the offset.
        bytes = f.read(size)   # Capture the specified number of bytes.

        print codecs.getencoder('hex')(bytes)

        if bytes == xls_sig:
            msg = '"{}" is an xls.'
        elif bytes == xlsx_sig:
            msg = '"{}" is an xlsx.'
        else:
            msg = '"{}" is not an Excel document.'
        print msg.format(filename)
```

#### Here is the output:

```
('0908100000060500', 8)
"spreadsheet.xls" is an xls.
('504b0506', 4)
"spreadsheet.xlsx" is an xlsx.
```

Comment: This method validates the file but when I try to read the xlsx file using XLRD I get an unsupported or corrupt file error.

Comment: Just as an edge case. If you have a .xls file saved by LibreOffice Calc, the offset is 1536.

Comment: Just a note: xlsx_sig = b'\x50\x4B\x05\06' is a bit misleading; should read open_xml_sig as files with this signature can also be .docx or .pptx files.

Answer (score 5):

Just an extension to PolyWhirl's post with a few edge cases that i came across.

```
def isExcelDoc(file):

    excelSigs = [
        ('xlsx', b'\x50\x4B\x05\x06', 2, -22, 4),
        ('xls', b'\x09\x08\x10\x00\x00\x06\x05\x00', 0, 512, 8),  #Saved from Excel
        ('xls', b'\x09\x08\x10\x00\x00\x06\x05\x00', 0, 1536, 8), #Saved from LibreOffice Calc
        ('xls', b'\x09\x08\x10\x00\x00\x06\x05\x00', 0, 2048, 8)  #Saved from Excel then saved from Calc
]

    for sigType, sig, whence, offset, size in excelSigs:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            f.seek(offset, whence)
            bytes = f.read(size)

            if bytes == sig:
                return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try and if not working, try another method.

```
import xlrd
import csv

try:
    # reading the file by xlrd
    ...
    print "Thanks for your Excel file"
except: # if you find specific Exception types, use them here
    try:
        # reading as CSV file
        ...
        print "thanks for your CSV file"
    except: # if you find specific Exception types, use them here
        print "sorry, now way, give me some usable file."
```

Comment: I would consider this to be the most Pythonic answer. See https://wiki.c2.com/?LookBeforeYouLeap