# I would like to check if an incoming file (the imported file) is a .csv or .xls or .xlxs in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

My problem statement is to find if the imported file is a `CSV` or `EXCEL` file in pandas. The input will be given from the command line as sys.argv[1] where sys.argv[1] is 'D:/Users/abc'

When the path along with file name is given in command line as a parameter, I have to check inside my script if sys.argv[1] is a CSV or EXCEL file

eg: python myscript.py D:/Users/abc [abc is the file name]

This should say if the file is CSV or EXCEL

I tried referring the answers from below link, but could not find exactly what I am looking for!

[How to check the uploaded file is csv or xls in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515791/how-to-check-the-uploaded-file-is-csv-or-xls-in-python)

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899497/checking-file-extension)

Comment: You have to describe your problem better here. What is exactly going wrong? Try to add an example so people can see what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since you give the filename "abc" as an example, I assume that you cannot decide on the file type based on extension. There are ways to look for the magic string in the header of the file, but that would be hard to get foolproof.

However, [it is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). So why don't you just assume it is an excel file, try to read it with `pd.read_excel` and if that fails, read it with `pd.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
try:
    df = pd.read_excel(sys.argv[1])
    filetype = 'EXCEL'
except Exception:
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
    filetype = 'CSV'
print(filetype)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import os


ExcelFile = request.FILES['your_file_name']
ext = os.path.splitext(ExcelFile.name)[-1].lower()

print(ext)
```

Now You can compare the ext with .csv, .xls, .xlsx etc...

with if statement

```
if ext=='.xlsx':
    #do something

elif ext=='.xls':
    #do something

else:
    #The uploaded file is not the required format
```